# Calculus, Optimizations, Minimum perimeter of rectangle

Tags: calculus, optimization

How do you find the length and width (minimum perimeter) of a rectangle that has the given area of 32 square feet.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know it is a square, you let $L$ be the length, $W$ be the width, the perimeter is ???, use the area equation to eliminate one variable and get the perimeter in terms of the other, take the derivative, set to zero....

Answer (score 0):

Let $l$ be the length and $w$ be the width. Then we have $A=lw =32$ . So you get $w=\frac{32}{l}$. Now the perimeter $P=2l+2w=2l+2\cdot \frac{32}{l}=\frac{2l^2+64}{l}$. Now take the derivative and find the critical point by setting the derivative to zero and then solve for $l$.